# How to make microwaved condensed milk caramel sauce properly?

Tags: milk, caramel, dulce-de-leche

When I tried making, but it always necomes pieces, and if I continue to turn it into a caramel brown colour, very dry, and turns into candy. What is the a recipe for making a caramel sauce in a microwave? I want it to be like canned dulce de leche. Unfortunately, I learned what cans might be leaching unsafe plastics (like BPA) into foods if boiled, so I won't do that.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to stick with using the microwave?  If its boiling the cans that concerns you, but not the boiling itself, you could always transfer your sweetened condensed milk into another container, like a mason jar, and boil that.  Mason jars are meant for canning, so should be completely safe for such an application.

Comment: What recipe or method are you following -- just microwaving the sweetened condensed milk? For how long?

Answer (score 2):

1. Put Sweetened Condensed Milk into a microwave safe bowl and whisk it thoroughly until its smooth and the thicker stickiness from the bottom of the can that has settled is evenly distributed again.
2. Place in microwave at 50% power for 2 minutes then take it out and stir thoroughly. Do NOT use full power!  If you do it will burn, and it will look similar to what you mentioned was happening to yours - it turns into a brown dry solid.
3. Put back in microwave (50% power again) for 1 minute increments, stirring in between each additional minute until it has reached the level of darkness you are looking for.

Hope this is what you are asking for.